# Проблемы с Wi-fi на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, драйвер, dual-boot

Не коректно работает Wi-fi на Ubuntu 18.04, постоянно рвет интернет.

Комп - Lenovo z80-70

На компе на 2-х разных жестких дисках установлены 2 независимые системы: Windows 10  и Ubuntu 18.04.

При тестировании скорости интернета с помощью http://www.speedtest.net/ru/ Windows даёт скорость загрузки 20-30Мбит/с и отдачи 50-60Мбит/с, в то же время Ubuntu 5-7Мбит/с и 7-10Мбит/с, иногда выдаёт ошибки типа нет связи.

На Windows сначало Wi-fi вообще не работал, но после скачвания из оф.сайта драйверов матери и Wi-fi, всё стало нормально. Wi-fi определяется в системе как **Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160.**

На Ubuntu по `lshw -C network` выводит:

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 93
       serial: f4:06:69:64:1a:54
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-45-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 ip=192.168.1.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:52 memory:c4000000-c4001fff
```

Проверил в [оф.репозитории](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/) , там последняя версия **iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode**. Этот же файл есть и в папке `/lib/firmware`

> **UPDATE**: роутер, к которому подключается комп - TP-LINK TL-WR841N.
>   Согласно документации он работает только на частоте 2,4 ГГц.
>
> **UPDATE2**:
>
> ```
> lspci | grep Wireless
> 03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 93)
> ```

Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: А что вам выдает `lspci | grep Wireless`?

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего убунту подключилась к точке доступа 2ГГц, а Виндовс переключилась на 5ГГц.
BSSID посмотри этой командой и пропиши тот что на 5ГГц в свойствах соединения wifi через меню.

```
iwlist wlp3s0 scanning | grep -C3 <name of your network>
```

Comment: точка доступа не поддерживает 5ГГц

Comment: Тогда отметьте что Мбит/с скорость, а не МБ.

Answer (score 3):

**Решение 1**

`sudo su & echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`

Это добавит дополнительную строку в файл конфигурации. Перезагрузите компьютер, и у вас все получится. Если это не помогает или у вас нет адаптера Wi-Fi Atheros, попробуйте другие решения.

**Решение 2**

Отключить 802.11n

`sudo rmmod iwlwif
 sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

Если вы не обнаружили значительного увеличения скорости беспроводного соединения, перезагрузите компьютер, чтобы отменить изменения и забыть об этом решении. НО, если у вас это работает и у вас более быстрый WiFi, вы должны сделать изменения постоянными, используя следующие команды:

`sudo su & echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

**Решение 3**

Исправление ошибки в Debian Avahi-daemon

Проблема медленного WiFi в Ubuntu также может быть связана с ошибкой в Avahi-демоне Debian. Ubuntu и многие другие дистрибутивы Linux основаны на Debian, поэтому эта ошибка распространяется и на эти дистрибутивы Linux. Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, вы должны отредактировать файл конфигурации nsswitch. Откройте терминал и используйте следующую команду:

`sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf`

**Решение 4**

Отключение IPv6 поддержки

`sudo su
 echo "#disable ipv6" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
 echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
 echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
 echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

**Решение 5**

Больше мощности для беспроводного адаптера:

`sudo iwconfig`

Это даст вам имя вашего беспроводного устройства. Обычно это должен быть wlan0. Теперь используйте следующую команду

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`

Источник: [itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/)

Comment: Р1:/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf - файл не существует. Р2: rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwif is not currently loaded. Р3: начал вроде более стабильно работать (почти пропали разрывы), скорость немного увеличилась, но не сильно. Р4:Р5: - ничего не изменило.

Comment: @Alex `echo "options wr841n swenc=1 fwlps=0 ips=0 ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/wr841n.conf` Попробуй.

Comment: @Alex если не сработает, то попробуй `ant_sel=2`. Тебе надо вот с этим значением играть `wr841n`. Это как раз твой адаптер.

Comment: Когда сделал Р3, система вроде начала работать стабильно, потом дальше пробовал другие решения, они ничего не изменили, но после нескольких перезагрузок, снова больше нет связи, чем есть... какое решение повлияло, не понятно... сегодня вечером попробую заново установить систему и на ней проверить, что получится

Comment: Возможно привязыватся к конкретному адаптеру не стоит, так как ноут используется и подключается в разных местах к разным точкам. На Виндовс проблем с этим нет, хотелось бы чтобы и Убунта хотя бы также работала. Просто тестировать в основном могу только дома...